# JSON Serialize Function returns empty string

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I have searched this on Google and trying everything to fix this, but still, the problem persists. Basically I have this C# class where I have modeled a credit card. I'm using Microsoft's `JsonSerializer` from the Nuget Packages to serialize this object but it returns an empty string. The class:

```
public class CreditCard
{
    public string cardNumber;
    public string cvv;
    public string owner;
    public string type;
    public string bank;
    public string expiry_date;

    public CreditCard(string cardNumber, string cvv, string owner, string type, string bank, string expiry_date)
    {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.cvv = cvv;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.type = type;
        this.bank = bank;
        this.expiry_date = expiry_date;
    }


    public CreditCard() 
    {

    }

    internal object getId()
    {
        return type + " " + cardNumber + " " + owner + " " + bank; 
    }
}
```

And when I do:

```
CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard(cardNumber, cvv, owner, type, bank, expiry_date);
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(creditCard);
```

The `json` string is empty. Note that the arguments are just strings from textbox values. I've tried adding an empty constructor to see if that could be the issue but to no avail. This error started happening only when I switched from `NewtonsoftJson` to `JsonSerializer`, so I don't know if that is the problem. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: JsonSerializer probably serializes using Properties and you have only Fields.

Comment: @OguzOzgul So how I should solve that?

Comment: Implement the class data as properties (having public fields is not good practice anyway), or see the documentation of JsonSerializer to serialize using fields. Changing the fields to properties is actually very simple: `public string cardNumber {get; set;}`

Comment: @OguzOzgul Oh setting the `{get; set; }` solves the problem? I wondered if that would solve but I didn't test it. Thanks a lot. By the way, why don't you post it as an answer, so I can tick it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that the problem started after switching to JsonSerializer.

It is probable that the JsonSerializer serializes using Properties but you have only Fields.

NOTE: as pointed out by @psychoboi111, it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Therefore;

Either implement the class data as properties (having public fields is not good practice anyway),

or see the documentation of JsonSerializer to serialize using fields.

Changing the fields to properties is actually very simple:

```
public string cardNumber {get; set;}
```

Comment: Gotta select this as the answer in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 4):

Please read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Is states clearly:

> By default, all public properties are serialized. You can specify
>   properties to exclude.
>
> Currently, fields are excluded.

So you need to convert your fields into properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @OguzOzgul did tell about the answer, but since you posted it I'm going to select it as the official answer. If you can upvote my answer as well! Thanks :)

Comment: Gotta select the other answer as he was the one who pointed it first! Thanks by the way :)

Comment: Kind of you. +1 from me :)